# adding ajax to capture email for abandons

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email

There is this form at http://orangeoctop.us/fifa-15-guide-preorder-2/.  I know, I know.  The UX is not loved by everybody.

I am trying to add ajax to the form where it will capture emails in case a user abandons the form (and adds them to an aweber email list - just trying to be as specific as possible).  None of the freelance ninjas, that have worked on the project have been able to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated! Code is below.

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="fs-form-wrap" id="fs-form-wrap">
            <div class="fs-title">
                <h1>FIFA 15 Guide Preorder</h1>
                <div class="codrops-top">
                    <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-info" href="#"><span>This fullscreen form is to preorder the fifa 15 guide</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="mailto:joey@orangeoctop.us">
                <ol class="fs-fields">
                    <li>
                        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">What's your name?</label>
                        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q1" name="q1" type="text" placeholder="Dean Moriarty" required/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2" data-info="We won't send you spam, we promise...">What's your email address?</label>
                        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q2" name="q2" type="email" placeholder="dean@road.us" required/>
                    </li>
                    <li data-input-trigger>
                        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q3" data-info="This will help us know what kind of service you need">How would you like to pay for the guide?</label>
                        <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
                            <span><input id="q3b" name="q3" type="radio" value="conversion"/><label for="q3b" class="radio-conversion" a ref="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?i=1375049&c=single&cl=229147">PayPal</label></span>
                            <span><input id="q3c" name="q3" type="radio" value="social"/><label for="q3c" class="radio-social">Credit Card</label></span>
                            <span><input id="q3a" name="q3" type="radio" value="mobile"/><label for="q3a" class="radio-mobile">BitPay</label></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol><!-- /fs-fields -->
                <button class="fs-submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
            </form><!-- /fs-form -->
        </div><!-- /fs-form-wrap -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="http://orangeoctop.us/wp-content/themes/athletica/fifa-15/fullscreenform/js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="http://orangeoctop.us/wp-content/themes/athletica/fifa-15/fullscreenform/js/selectFx.js"></script>
    <script src="http://orangeoctop.us/wp-content/themes/athletica/fifa-15/fullscreenform/js/fullscreenForm.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var formWrap = document.getElementById( 'fs-form-wrap' );

            [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'select.cs-select' ) ).forEach( function(el) {    
                new SelectFx( el, {
                    stickyPlaceholder: false,
                    onChange: function(val){
                        document.querySelector('span.cs-placeholder').style.backgroundColor = val;
                    }
                });
            } );

            new FForm( formWrap, {
                onReview : function() {
                    classie.add( document.body, 'overview' ); // for demo purposes only
                }
            } );
        })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using Javascript or JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {     
        $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
            var email = $("#q2");    // Gets whatever is in the email input
            if (email.length) {      // Checks to make sure that there is a value
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/MethodToSaveEmail",
                    data: {
                    "Email": email,
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // No need to do anything
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        // The user doesn't care if this fails
                    }
                }); // end ajax call
            } // end if email has value
        }); // end beforeunload event
   }); // end doc ready
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Fixed typo

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried this, not getting any results. Maybe getting caught up on the method to save email with aweber.

Comment: Do you have the jquery library loaded before this script is called?  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That and if you copy/pasted directly I made a typo... it's $(document).ready(.... not documnet